# The concept of non-measurability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is basically a foundational question. So I understand the development of the theory of Lebesgue measure to deal with those situations where we have difficulties applying the Riemann integral like in the case of infinitely many discontinuities or unbounded functions. But so far what I am gathering is that if $A$ is a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then we cannot really describe $A$ or its elements very well as we can do for the Cantor set for instance.

I am still developing my knowledge in this field and would love to hear some opinions about non-measurable sets.

Also is their a list of properties related to non-measurable sets. Like every set $E$ with $\mu(E) > 0$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure has a non-measurable subset.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. The standard proof that not all subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are measurable gives a clear description of a non-measurable set. That description doesn't give a recipe for deciding membership of that set, but that is to be expected for a construction that depends on the axiom of choice. What is the "list of properties" you refer to in your last paragraph?

Comment: @RobArthan Ex: every set $E$ with $\mu(E) > 0$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure has a non-measurable subset.

Comment: "*opinions* about nonmeasurable sets"? That's a bit like asking for opinions about even numbers, or parabolas, or cosines. Whatever do you mean, and why would anyone want such things?